# GIS Mobile App with offline capabilities

Tags: open-source

I am looking for an app where you can upload shapefiles layers to and use it to navigate to the specific features. Basically we digitize features and then go out to check if they are still there. Does anyone maybe have a recommendation? It needs to have offline capabilities.